# Unable to write data on QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement a client/server application using Qt/C++, but whenever I try to write data on `QTcpSocket`, then the program is getting terminated. I get the following error :

> Server started. The program has unexpectedly finished.
>
> /home/pavan/qt/build-server-Desktop-Debug/server crashed.

Here is my code:

```
void server::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    Server=new QTcpServer(this);
    if(Server->listen(QHostAddress::Any,ui->lineEdit->text().toInt()))
        qDebug()<<"Server started";
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Could not start server";
        return;
    }

    QTcpSocket *socket = Server->nextPendingConnection();

    socket->write("Hii server");
    socket->flush();
    socket->waitForBytesWritten((3000));

    socket->close();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the return value of nextPendingConnection. It could return 0 if case no  pending connections. It could lead to crash. And you can try to use debugger which help u to identify and trouble shooting a lot.

Comment: Hi Dean, yes it returns zero as you said, now i am not understanding how to proceed further, could you please help me out.

Comment: Suppose you already know signal and slot concept in Qt. Actually there is an signal called void QTcpServer::newConnection(). You just connect this signal to your slot which process the incoming connection. Please refer to the example in the link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-network-fortuneserver-example.html